# How can I compile a C program for multiple cores with mingw?

Tags: compilation, mingw

I have a C program that I am compiling with mingw, but it runs on only one core of my 8-core machine.  How do I compile it to run on multiple cores?

(To clarify: I am not looking to use multiple cores to compile, as compilation time is low.  It's runtime where I want to use my full CPU capacity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way but to write a multithread program. You need to first see how to split your tasks into independent parts which can be then run in threads simultaneously.

It cannot be fully automated. You may consider making use of the last additions of the [C11 standard](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-finally-gets-a-new-standard/232800444), or taking a look at pthreads or [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).